# Missing switch routes in react router switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Ok, heres my problem.
I am using react router and the switch is only showing the '/' route and nothing else. I am seeing this in the developer tools react plugin.
I have omitted the import statements, 
My code App.js

```
    const Header = () => {return (
        <div>
          Hello
        </div>

  );
}

export const App = () => {
  return (
       <BrowserRouter>
         <div>
         <Header />
           <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
              <Route exact path="/login" component={MainPage}/>

           </Switch>
         </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
);}
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "first-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-autocomplete": "^1.8.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-date-picker": "^6.10.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-link": "^2.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

And the output in react console window
[only 1 route visible, click here for my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duOpt.png)

Well, yes, that may be the case and how it looks in the debugger. 
However, this was only part of the problem. I have another component that is MainPage which has another Switch. 
This is also empty in the React-debugger, and when I use the buttons, it goes to a new page and just shows up empty. I am attaching the MainPage component as well

```
export const MainPage = () => {
    return (
        <div><div>
          <Navbar>
            <Navbar.Header>
              <Navbar.Brand>
                Attendance App
              </Navbar.Brand>
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Nav>
              <NavItem eventKey='updatePage' href="showUpdatePage">
                Update Attendance
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey='addEmployee' href="/showAddEmployeePage">
                Add Employee
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey='reports' href="reportsPage">
                Reports
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar></div><div>        
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/showAddEmployeePage' component={AddEmployee} />
            <Route exact path='/reportsPage' component={Reports} />
            <Route exact path='/showUpdatePage' component={UpdateAttendance} />
            <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
          </Switch>  
        </div></div>)
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that all files are saved? If so then try restarting dev server?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? You've described the intended behaviour of Switch. It's supposed to obliterate all but the matching route.

Comment: I have updated with more information above